# Jquery GetJson - How to read the reply?

Tags: jquery, json, reply

i have always the same problem, it is hard for me to read the reply from a json post.

**For example**

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/live/subscriptions?alt=json', function(data) {

  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {

      console.log(item.feed.link.i); // did not work

   });

});
```

**The Reply**

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gd":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005","xmlns$yt":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007","id":{"$t":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/live/subscriptions"},"updated":{"$t":"2011-03-04T08:31:20.148Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#subscription"}],"title":{"$t":"Subscriptions of live","type":"text"},"logo":{"$t":"http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif"},"link":[{"rel":"related","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/live"},{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http://www.youtube.com/profil ....
```

Sometimes i need an hour to get it -.- ...

How do you read this? Any nice ideas?

Thanks in advance! 
Peter

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting? Is it `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran the code you pasted in my Firebug console without the `feed` I saw this object model:

[image]

So as you can see `feed` is not a child of  `item`, and that's why you were getting an error.

Try this instead

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/live/subscriptions?alt=json', function(data) {

  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {

      console.log(item.gd$feedLink); // did not work

   });

});
```